# Is there a way to figure out what data is rarely accessed on my SQL Server databases?

Tags: sql-server

So we're exploring our options in terms of migrating our SQL Server database to another engine. A question that we've been asked when talking with other providers is how much of our stored information could potentially live in cold storage / archives.

Is there a way to figure this out through SSMS or any other third party tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats view, but it is cleared on server restart, so might not be sufficiently reliable.

Look at all datetime columns, eg.

```
SELECT t.name,
  (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (last_user_seek), (last_user_scan), (last_user_lookup),   (last_user_update)) AS value(v)) as [MaxDate]
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats us 
join sys.tables t
on t.object_id = us.object_id
```

Comment: It should be fine, the only time the server restarts is when there's a power cut which hasn't happened in a while, I'll try this and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly, but what column am I looking out for to gather the information I need? Thanks

Comment: edited answer, for more look into detailed ms doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16